# Retrieve the event name and the control that triggered a postback, ideally the function name that will be called

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an application that started as a small web forms project and got quickly very large. I would like to log every event triggered plus check user's rights for the specified action.

Instead of adding the functionality in each and every event I thought that a good way would be to create a base class that overrides the default 'System.Web.UI.Page' and check each event call in the base class.

Here is the code for that class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for BasePage
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public BasePage()
        {
            // Adding functionality to the "on load" event of the base class (Page)
            base.Load += new EventHandler(BasePage_Load);
            base.Unload += new EventHandler(BasePage_Unload);
            base.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(BasePage_LoadComplete);
        }

        private void BasePage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogEverything();
            AccessCheck();
        }

        private void BasePage_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogEverything();
            AccessCheck();
        }

        protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, string eventArgument)
        {
            LogEverything();
            base.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument);
        }


        private void BasePage_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogEverything();
        }

        private bool LogEverything()
        {
            string sRawUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
            string sQueryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString();
            string sPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
            string sHttpMethod = HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod;
            string sUserAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
            string sUserAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            string sEventTarget = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
            string sEventArgument = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
            string sEventValidation = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["__EVENTVALIDATION"];

            // TODO: find the event that triggered the postback

            return Logging.append(Logging.logLevelType.Info, "Baseclass is here!");
        }

        private bool AccessCheck()
        {
            // enforce security here ...
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You might notice that it's not complete as I am still researching this option. I haven't found a way to retrieve the triggered event so that I can log the called function name and also check if the user has the right to call that function. Is it possible? Even a dirty hack would do.

Comment: Check to see if other HTTP Form variables contain what you need

Comment: You have an authorization system which checks if the user is authorized to execute `Page_Load` or `Page_Unload`? That makes no sense at all. Also, do you really want every request to wait until the file is not longer locked by another request that wants to log something?

Comment: Tim, yes there is an authentication system that currently only checks for access to a page, so for example a non-admin user is denied access to admin.aspx

Comment: Jeremy, I checked while debugging but found nothing. Also, I searched on the internet and did not find anything useful

Comment: @Uphill_What'1: Use ASP.NET membership which supports this kind of file level authorization by default and don't log every method in every request. That might work(although not best-practise) in a single user environment but not with multiple users in an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than overriding the default 'System.Web.UI.Page' class, you can intercept events using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/). You can check out the following article to get a walk-through

[PostSharp Principles: Day 11 – EventInterceptionAspect](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-11-e28093-Interception-e28093-Part-3.aspx)

You can build an aspect that will calls out to your custom method when the event is fired. Use the custom method to log calls and an access check. Aspects can be applied globally to save you some work using multicasting.

[PostSharp Principles: Day 2 - Applying Aspects with Multicasting Part 1](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Day-2-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-1.aspx)

[PostSharp Principles: Day 2 - Applying Aspects with Multicasting Part 2](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Day-3-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-2.aspx)